# Is it valid to assume that principal components follow Gaussian distribution?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, pca, covariance-matrix

My professor said that we can assume that principal components follow Gaussian distribution.

If we consider the covariance matrix as a linear operator and all data points as linearly transformed data from white data following standard Gaussian distribution (rotation & scaling matrix can be induced from the orthonormal eigenvectors(=principal components axis) of the covariance matrix), then it's plausible in some respects. (reference : [http://www.cs.utah.edu/~tch/CS4640F2019/resources/A%20geometric%20interpretation%20of%20the%20covariance%20matrix.pdf](http://www.cs.utah.edu/%7Etch/CS4640F2019/resources/A%20geometric%20interpretation%20of%20the%20covariance%20matrix.pdf))

However, in my opinion, even if we consider the original data as transformed, the white data just have the identity covariance matrix, not following the standard Gaussian. So, I think the Gaussian assumption on principal components is not valid in general.

To summarize, my question is "Is it the Gaussian assumption on principal components valid? If not, are there some cases in which such assumptions are good to use?"

I'm not sure if my question was well described because of my poor English.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: That is a silly notion.  Of course they are not normally distributed.  If you have an outlier-prone process, then so will the distributions of the PCs be outlier-prone.  The mixing reduces the non- normality somewhat, but it certainly does not eliminate it.

Comment: A standard multivariate Gaussian has identity covariance matrix

Comment: Is your professor assuming a Gaussian distribution of the original data?